# Can't access nested mapping in another contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping

I have a contract:

```
contract KeyValueStorage {
    mapping (address => mapping(bytes32 => uint256)) refreshTime;
    ....
}
```

and in another file:

```
import "./KeyValueStorage.sol";
contract GlobalGeneric {
    KeyValueStorage globalS;
    constructor(KeyValueStorage storage_) public {
        globalS = storage_;
    }
    function claimInterests(address _memberAddr, bytes32 _identifier) public returns (bool success) {
        require(now > globalS.refreshTime[_memberAddr][_identifier] + 90 days);
        .....
    }
....
}
```

But I got an error as `refreshTime not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract KeyValueStorage`

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping is **private** by default. If you do not precise it's public with the keyword `public` before the mapping's name, you won't be able to access it unless you provide a getter.

`mapping (address => mapping(bytes32 => uint256)) public refreshTime;`

Once it's done, to access a value, you can only do it the following way :

```
require(now > globalS.refreshTime(_memberAddr, _identifier) + 90 days);
```

You will note that you have to pass the keys as parameters. For every public variable, Solidity is automatically creating a getter, and for mappings, the getter takes in parameters the keys needed to access a value, as you remarked.

Comment: That works! Wondering how can I edit the value if it is a getter function. For example, how do I modify `globalS.refreshTime(_memberAddr, _identifier)`?

Comment: No, a getter is a constant function and does not modify the state of the contract. You will need to use a setter for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can Even do something this way

```
contract KeyValueStorage {
    mapping (address => mapping(bytes32 => uint256)) internal refreshTime;
}
```

---

```
import "./KeyValueStorage.sol";
contract GlobalGeneric is KeyValueStorage {

    function claimInterests(address _memberAddr, bytes32 _identifier) public view returns (bool success) {
        require(now > refreshTime[_memberAddr][_identifier] + 90 days);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: __Inheriting__ `KeyValueStorage` — as opposed to __referencing__ an instance of it — means that `refreshTime` will be a different mapping from the one that OP wants to get.